# Scalability of open source XML Databases

Tags: exist-db, basex, xml-database, sedna

We are looking to develop a reporting application that reports on data stored in a large number of XML files.  ~3,000,000 files ranging in size from 7KB to 5MB (Each file conforms to the same schema). I’m guessing that there will be about around 200GB of XML.   I’m looking at a number of open source XML databases (Sedna, BaseX and eXist-db) and I’m not sure how well these systems will scale, I read a comparison of these three database [here](http://share.aweta.nl/weblinks/?id=f29c21d4897f78948b91f03172341b7b&filename=XML%20Database%20Comparison.pdf). Which is where my concerns of scalability originated from.

Some details regarding what we want to do are: We won’t be changing the data in any of the XML files and new files will be added daily. Since we are concerned with reporting query performance is important to us, and the time it takes to add and index new files isn’t a high priority for us.

I’m wondering if anyone has experience using these systems at similar scales?  I’ve looked at the BaseX [statistics page](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Statistics) and see some fairly large XML instances but no mention of performance.

We don’t require an open source product and the MarkLogic system looks like it can fit the bill nicely, but I’m curious what’s been done with open source products.

Answer (score 8):

I think it is impossible to answer your question with either a `yes` or `no`. It is really impossible to state anything about performance from the little details that you have given.

Performance is typically based on the queries that you want to perform and the distribution of your data. Not to mention, what you consider to be "acceptable".

In the [paper you referenced](http://share.aweta.nl/weblinks/?id=f29c21d4897f78948b91f03172341b7b&filename=XML%20Database%20Comparison.pdf), it is interesting to note that they state that they could not get the *new range indexes* in eXist 2.2 preview to work. Certainly without those, they would have seen much worse performance. Also at the end they state that they will select Sedna as they can overcome the problems with Sedna, it was not clear to me why that was, i.e. do they have C++ devs that can work with Sedna but they don't have Java devs that could work with eXist or BaseX? Finally, the version of Java they used for testing eXist and BaseX is rather old, the next release of eXist (3.0) will only support Java 8 and newer.

I would be surprised if you could not store 200GB of data into BaseX, eXist or Sedna, but without knowing your data and the sort of queries you want to execute, I cannot comment on query performance.

I think you would be best to do a small trial of either one or all, in a manner not dissimilar to that linked article.

Comment: That the author disregarded eXist 2.2's new range indexes was a rather significant caveat. I wish the author had sought assistance from the eXist mailing list; it's trivial to configure this. Also the article was repeatedly contradictory; for example, "When the collection size increases, BaseX and Sedna remain more or less constant in time whereas BaseX increases linear in time" (p.7). It's a shame that the article wasn't proofread. Nonetheless, the article represents one user's/organization's fairly rigorous study of performance, and all three projects should take it seriously.

Answer (score 3):

Just want to share my experience on this topic. My experience is limited to much smaller data sets - that is roughly about 50k documents of about 1GB total size. We use Sedna XML DB for this purpose. We do not change documents but rather overwrite existing documents when changes occur and have a lot of read-only XQueries including big reports.

Shortly, my opinion is Sedna won't work for you unless you find a way to replicate it to another server to be used for reading. I have experienced major performance issues related to collection locks with a rather moderate load on the database when performing some long-lasting reporting XQueries. As far as I know, Sedna does not offer replication capabilities but you can probably adopt some solution on top of Sedna. For example, quick googling revealed [some research](http://www.academia.edu/783785/RepliX_A_mechanism_to_replication_of_xml_data) in this area. You can try asking on the [Sedna mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/sedna-discussion). Among other disadvantages are lack of XQuery 3.0 support and seemingly frozen further development. However, the support is still quite active on the mailing list.

Also I have some experience with eXist-db but I use it more as a XML processing and pipelining platform rather than an XML storage. Still it looks a bit more promising in relation to scaling. Although I have not used its replication capabilities, they are mentioned in the [docs](http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/faq_performance.xml?q=scaling&field=all&id=D2.2.5#D2.2.5). I suggest you try searching/asking on the [mailing list](http://exist-open.markmail.org/) as well.